# How to integrate an iframe in a custom email template

Tags: email, iframe

I am setting up custom email templates to send out automatically after creating a lead. All fine so far. Now I´ve tried to embed an ifram which seems all fine until I have a look in the preview. The preview behaves like the video just doesn´t exist. All else (links, pictures, text) is presented as it should be.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/81389903" width="270" height="204" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen</iframe>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't include the open bracket (`<`) in your initial post. Was that a typo?

Comment: yes was just a typo :-)

Comment: another user showed me this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967832/embed-youtube-vimeo-videos-into-email-template)
Can it be that we simply can´t embed a video?

Comment: what browser or email client are you using.?? Is there any error in console when you open email. Try opening email in chrome.

Comment: I use Chrome for the preview and Outlook for the mail itself.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing nothing wrong. [Many clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/08/do-iframes-work-in-email/) simply don't allow iframe tags.